# The task 'rp_Log' was not handled in the plugins file. The following tasks are registered: gmail:get-messages

Tags: cypress

I am writing the cypress test for my website. I have included reportportal js client in my test and my test was running without any issues.
Now I have added gmail-tester for email verification. When I run it I am getting the error
**cy.task('rp_Log') failed with the following error:
The task 'rp_Log' was not handled in the plugins file. The following tasks are registered: gmail:get-messages**

my plugin/index.js file looks like this

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
// ***********************************************************
// This example plugins/index.js can be used to load plugins
//
// You can change the location of this file or turn off loading
// the plugins file with the 'pluginsFile' configuration option.
//
// You can read more here:
// https://on.cypress.io/plugins-guide
// ***********************************************************

// This function is called when a project is opened or re-opened (e.g. due to
// the project's config changing)

/**
 * @type {Cypress.PluginConfig}
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const registerReportPortalPlugin = require('@reportportal/agent-js-cypress/lib/plugin');
const debug = require('debug');
const path = require('path');
const gmail_tester = require('gmail-tester');


module.exports = (on) => registerReportPortalPlugin(on);

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on("before:browser:launch", (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
    if (browser.name === "chrome"&& browser.isHeadless) {
      launchOptions.args.push('--disable-gpu');
      return launchOptions;
    }
  });
  on("task", {
    "gmail:get-messages": async args => {
      const messages = await gmail_tester.get_messages(
        path.resolve(__dirname, "credentials.json"),
        path.resolve(__dirname, "token.json"),
        args.options
      );
      return messages;
    }
  });
};
```

My test file looks like this

```
describe('Launch website',() => {
    it('Home visit',() => {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
        cy.log("Visited the page")
        cy.screenshot("Launch_name.png")
        cy.rp_screenshot("Launch.png")
    })
})
```

When I run the test I can see the my page is getting launched and it's printing the log also. But after that it's telling cy.task('rp_log') is not defined instead it can see the gmail get messages.
can anyone help me to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved an issue. We cant use two modules.export in index.js file. The answer should look like this

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
registerReportPortalPlugin(on);
  on("before:browser:launch", (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
    if (browser.name === "chrome"&& browser.isHeadless) {
      launchOptions.args.push('--disable-gpu');
      return launchOptions;
    }
  });
  on("task", {
    "gmail:get-messages": async args => {
      const messages = await gmail_tester.get_messages(
        path.resolve(__dirname, "credentials.json"),
        path.resolve(__dirname, "token.json"),
        args.options
      );
      return messages;
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue can you help me out here. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72018951/receiving-the-task-event-has-not-been-registered-in-the-plugins-file-you-must]